# How to find position of uiscrollview when scroling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Hi I have problem with getting position and scrollevent.

I have customScrollView:

.h

```
@interface MyScroll : UIScrollView<UIScrollViewDelegate>

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyScroll

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
}
```

But when I scroll I don't see data in LOGS.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you set the delegate (i.e. `self.scrollView.delegate = self;`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the Delegate.

```
ScrollView.delegate=self;
```

It's very Simple

```
int page = ScrollView.contentOffset.x / ScrollView.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"%d",page);
```

Try this code using this you will get the current page of ScrollView.

Comment: Do you have any idea How use it in custom uiscrollview?

Comment: if you adding custom scroll view then create outlet and try this code ... helpful to you,...

Comment: Try to put this code - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender   this method......

Comment: tnx, its working. Now I can get position on scroll when is stoped:)

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    int page = ScrollView.contentOffset.x / ScrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%d",page);
}
```

Comment: you got the index of current page